# rails, jquery, javascript, jqvmap can't load multiple countries

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jqvmap

I am trying to implement jqvmap and have multiple regions selected and colored. How do I pass a variable from Rails into this javascript so that the 'selectedRegions' variable will work? I've tried endlessly but can't seem to make the JS read the variable correctly.

JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var areas1=['CA','US'];
      jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({ 
        map: 'world_en',
        selectedColor: '#FFC864',
        selectedRegions: areas1

      });
  });
  </script>
```

The selectedRegions variable needs take in format: ['CA', 'US'], but when I pass in this format from my Rails helper method, it does not work. Any JS experts out there with some thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your controller looks something like this:

```
def show
  # set an instance variable in the controller
  @areas1 = [ 'CA', 'US' ]

  # render code....
end
```

in the view your selectedRegions (assuming it's in an erb page) could simply be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var areas1=['CA','US'];
    jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap({ 
      map: 'world_en',
      selectedColor: '#FFC864',
      selectedRegions: [<%= @areas1.map {|str| "'#{ str }'" }.join(',') %>]
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi GSP! Thanks for your help with this. I tried the exact code you put, but now the map doesn't even load. =/

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like after doing that? View source in the browser should help you be able to debug things like this.